# Using delogo twice to mask a Video

Tags: ffmpeg

I know that the below line will mask the video

```
ffmpeg -i "aunt1.mp4" -vf delogo=x=4:y=0:w=120:h=22 -c:a copy au1.mp4
```

However I want to delogo in two sections of the video in one command. I tried this separated by comma but didnt work

```
ffmpeg -i "aunt1.mp4" -vf delogo=x=4:y=0:w=120:h=22, delogo=x=40:y=50:w=120:h=22 -c:a copy au1.mp4
```

Comment: What happened that makes you say it didn't work?

Comment: I was missing the quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what doesn't work, so taking a guess:

```
ffmpeg -i "aunt1.mp4" -vf "delogo=x=4:y=0:w=120:h=22, delogo=x=40:y=50:w=120:h=22" -c:a copy au1.mp4
```